# How do I allow thead and th tags in wordpress 4.9 visual editor?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get the visual editor in wordpress 4.9 to stop removing the thead and th tags when I switch between text and visual mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying the figure out the same thing. The only solution I have right now is to always use Text editor.